# React Native Navigation backButton at TopBar customise

Tags: react-native, navigation, native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

After long searching for that how to customise the back button on the react-native-navigation I finally gave up. So my idea is to use custom back button if it is possible because it will be the easiest option I think. For example ....

```
backButton: {
        id: "backButton",
        icon: require("../../assets/logo.png"),
    }
```

But what happens here is that the icon gets coloured in blue like it is a back arrow. The problem is that is in fact text which have different colours on some chars and I don't want the colour of the png to be changed at all. And the biggest problem is that if it gets changed there is absolutely no way to revert it.

So my question is: Is there any way this logo.png when I put it for icon of the backButton it not to get colour changed? Or if there is no way that to happen this way is there any way this to be done at all?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

The back button can be customised with a `backButton` option as described in the [docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/stack#styling-the-back-button)

Comment: Yes I have read maybe all of the documentation but I couldn't find answer of my question which was is there any way for this logo.png which i am importing not to change its colour, because now it goes blue by default, and yes I can change its colour to whatever I want but the point is not that. I want it to remain the colour it originally is. Is there any way that to happen. Thanks. :)